# how to make comparevalidator don't catch character?

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation

I have a textbox that can input anything inside.
And a CompareValidator that check the number in that textbox is less than 100.

```
<asp:CompareValidator runat="server" ErrorMessage="The number is not over 100!" ControlToValidate="txtNumber" Display="Dynamic" ForeColor="Red" ValueToCompare="100" Type="Integer" Operator="LessThan"></asp:CompareValidator>
```

When I put the number that over than 100, it's OK. But when I put a normal character that isn't a number, the validator still fire. But I don't want it fire when the character in textbox isn't number.

My textbox can input anything, don't recommend me make that textbox just input number only.

How can I do that?

Sorry for my english! :(

Comment: In that case you should use CustomValidator which gives you all the flexibility you want.

Comment: Yes CustomValidator will be good though i think in this case you should be using range validator.